# Compiling stockfish 7 producing 5 linker errors

Tags: c++, linker, chess

I downloaded [stockfish 7](https://stockfishchess.org/) for windows and I am trying to compile the code. I know the binaries already exist, but I am curious about the code. Anyway, I am using visual studio 2015 and I received 5 linker errors upon building the project:

> Error  LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl Tablebases::init(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &)" (?init@Tablebases@@YAXABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
>   .....
>   .....

Any idea how to resolve this issue?

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik I know what an undefined reference is. I am asking how to resolve the issue....

Comment: The linked answer tells you how.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't think so, cause the chess folder does not have library files. Am asking particularly about stockfish available source.

Comment: reopened - OP's issue was not resolved by the alleged duplicate

Comment: I know how to solve the problem but I can't answer because the question is closed.

Comment: @Ken_White The problem is related to Syzygy tablebase. You shouldn't close a question just because you don't know anything. This is an insult. Look at the `Tablebases` symbol in the question, it explains a lot.

Comment: @StudentT It is unclear what you regard as insulting and why.  If you can [edit] the question so that it's clear what is being asked and how it is different from the nominated duplicate, we should be able to reopen this.  Could you do that please?

Comment: As mentioned in the now-deleted Meta question and [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252252/this-question-may-already-have-an-answer-here-but-it-does-not), the information available here in the comments should be added to the question itself, to make clear why it is not a duplicate. Without all that information, the question is correctly closed as a duplicate.